# resizing JTable that is inside JScrollBar

Tags: java, file, oop, user-interface, jtable

can someone tell me how to resize a `JTable` that is inside a `JScrollBar`?

[my JTable inside JScrollBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LpflC.png)

also, i have `JPanel` for `registering` and the `JTable` is the verification that the record was saved so after the `registering` the JTable will appear. however, if i set a size to `JTable` or even the size of `JScrollPane`, nothing will appear in my `JTable`.

here is the code for my JTable:

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.awt.*;

public void setColumns(){
        ViewTablePanel.tblModel=new DefaultTableModel();
        ViewTablePanel.tblModel.setColumnIdentifiers(column);
    }

public class ViewTablePanel extends JPanel{
    static JTable tblVoters;
    static DefaultTableModel tblModel;

    ViewTablePanel(){       
        setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Voter's Information Table"));

        data=new Database();
        setColumns();
        data.retrieveRecords();

        ViewTablePanel.tblVoters=new JTable(ViewTablePanel.tblModel);


        add(new JScrollPane(ViewTablePanel.tblVoters));
    }
}
```

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.table.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
public class Database {
    static String [] column={"VOTERS NUMBER", 
        "LAST NAME", "FIRST NAME", 
        "MIDDLE NAME", "GENDER", 
        "STATUS", "WEIGHT", 
        "HEIGHT", "BIRTH MONTH", 
        "BIRTH DAY", "BIRTH YEAR", 
        "BIRTH CITY/MUN.", "BIRTH PROVINCE", 
        "PROVINCE", "CITY/MUN", "BARANGAY", 
        "HOUSE NO./ST.", 
        "# MONTHS IN CITY RESIDENCE", 
        "# YEARS IN CITY RESIDENCE", 
        "# YEARS IN PHIL. RESIDENCE", 
        "OCCUPATION", "TIN NUMBER", 
        "CITIZENSHIP", "CITIZEN SINCE", 
        "FIRST-MOTHER", "MIDDLE-MOTHER", 
        "LAST-MOTHER", "FIRST-FATHER", 
        "MIDDLE-FATHER", "LAST-FATHER"};
    static Vector rows;
    static File fileNew;
    static FileWriter fileWrite;
    static FileReader fileRead;
    static Scanner read;

    public Database() {
        fileNew=new File("Voters.txt");
        fileWrite=null;
        fileRead=null;
        read=null;
    }
    public void retrieveRecords(){
        String holdStr="";
        try {
            fileRead=new FileReader(fileNew);
            read=new Scanner(fileRead);

            while(read.hasNext()){
                holdStr+=read.nextLine()+"\n";
            }
            read.close();

            StringTokenizer strToken=new StringTokenizer(holdStr, "/");

            while(strToken.hasMoreElements()){
                rows=new Vector();
                for(int i=0; i<column.length; i++){
                    rows.add(strToken.nextElement());
                }
                ViewTablePanel.tblModel.addRow(rows);
            }

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

and here is where i call the `JTable` to be called in the `main JFrame`

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class ViewPanel extends JPanel{

    ViewPanel(){
        setName("panelView");
        setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        setPreferredSize(new Dimension(880,70));

        add(new JScrollPane(new ViewTablePanel()), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        add(new ViewButtonsPanel(), BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    }
}
```

please help and any suggestions thank you so much :)

Comment: You can check the drap and drop gui to resize the table , when I used to work on swing, I drag and drop the jtable, then click the right mouse button, and select `surround by scrollPane`

Comment: @ElSam thanks for the suggestion!! :) but i'm trying to do hard coding as i already started at the same time i don't think i will understand the code in drag and drop. but thank you anyways :)

Comment: Regarding the code generated by the drag and drop for jTable, it's really easy.

Comment: Try calling `setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_OFF)` on your table.  Documentation: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setAutoResizeMode-int-

Answer (score 1):

A JScrollPane manages a viewport, optional vertical and horizontal scroll bars, and optional row and column heading viewports. the scrollable client (like a Jtable) must be put in the ViewPort view and you just have to resize the scrollPane not the client .

check the doc : [JScrollPane doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JScrollPane.html)

```
public class ViewTablePanel extends JPanel{
  static JTable tblVoters;
  static DefaultTableModel tblModel;

  ViewTablePanel(){       
    setBorder(BorderFactory.createTitledBorder("Voter's Information Table"));

    data=new Database();
    setColumns();
    data.retrieveRecords();

    ViewTablePanel.tblVoters=new JTable(ViewTablePanel.tblModel);

    JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane();
    scrollPane.setBounds(x,y,width,height);
    add(scrollPane);
    scrollPane.setViewportView(ViewTablePanel.tblVoters);
  }
}
```

I hope it helps